# No Routes Matched Location Bug

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Okay so I've gone through some answers provided to this problem here but seems not to fix my issue. SO I am making use of react-router-dom 6 for my routing. The base "/" route works as expected by when I visit another route in a different file, it goes blank and show no routes matched loaction "/path name". But if I place a "*" as route path, everything works fine but this will become a problem if I'm handling authentication. Below is my code, I sincerely need some tips:

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
          <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

App.js

```
import "./App.css";
import { DASHBOARD, LOGIN } from "./routes";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { LoginPage } from "./pages";
import DashBoardLayout from "./pages/dashboard-layout/DashBoardLayout";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route path={DASHBOARD} element={<DashBoardLayout />} />
        <Route exact path={LOGIN} element={<LoginPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

route.js

```
export const LOGIN = "/";
export const DASHBOARD = "*";
export const CREATE_JOB = "/create";
export const EDIT_JOB = "/edit";
```

dashboardlayout.js

```
import "./style.scss";
import { Layout, Menu } from "antd";
import { Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import TopNavigation from "../../components/top-navigation/TopNavigation";
import { CREATE_JOB, EDIT_JOB } from "../../routes";
import { CreateJobPage, EditJobPage } from "../../pages";
import DashBoardIcon from "../../assets/dashboard_icon.svg";
import JobsIcon from "../../assets/jobs_icon.svg";
import UsersIcon from "../../assets/users_icon.svg";

const { Content, Sider } = Layout;
const { SubMenu } = Menu;

const DashBoardLayout = () => {
  return (
    <Layout className="dashboard__container">
      <TopNavigation />
      <Layout>
        <Sider width={300} className="dashbord__sidebar">
          <Menu defaultSelectedKeys={["1"]}>
            <Menu.Item key="1">
              <img src={DashBoardIcon} alt="dashboard icon" />
              Dashbord
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="2">
              <Link to={CREATE_JOB}>
                <img src={JobsIcon} alt="jobs icon" />
                Jobs
              </Link>
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="3">
              <Link to={EDIT_JOB}>
                <img src={UsersIcon} alt="users icon" />
                Users
              </Link>
            </Menu.Item>
          </Menu>
        </Sider>
        <Layout style={{ padding: "24px 24px" }}>
          <Content
            style={{
              padding: 24,
              margin: 0,
              justifyContent: "center",
              display: "flex",
            }}
          >
            <Routes>
              <Route path={CREATE_JOB} element={<CreateJobPage />} />
              <Route path={EDIT_JOB} element={<EditJobPage />} />
            </Routes>
          </Content>
        </Layout>
      </Layout>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default DashBoardLayout;
```

So any tips on how I can go about this? I want to remove that (*) from the route because it is causing problems in authentication.

Thanks for your anticipated assistance

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I solved this issue by making use of one Routes import in the dashoadlayout. React was finding it difficult to locate the new route in the dashboardlayout and that of the App.js file. And what about the App.js file? well I used a conditional rendering with my userToken to render each page if the user is logged in or not while removing the routes there and its working fine.